# Chaining function in Scala using dot notation

Tags: scala, pipe-forward-operator

So far, the only native method of chaining functions together in Scala I know of is using andThen/compose. It gets the job done but still looks very clunky. For example, if I have 3 functions to apply to a value ( f1(f2(f3(value))) ), I have to do something like that:

```
(f1 _ andThen f2 andThen f3)(value)
```

Problems get even worse when the chain is longer and the functions require more than 1 parameter. F# solves this conundrum very elegantly with the '|>' operator, but that approach doesn't work well in Scala, since the language relies a lot on dot notation and currying is optional.

So the question is, is it possible to do something like this in Scala:

```
def addNumber(i: Int, s: String) = s + i
def doubleString(s: String) = (s + s, (s + s).length)
def trimString(i: (String, Int)) = i._1.substring(0, i._2-1)

addNumber(1,"Hello").doubleString.trimString
```

In other words can we chain functions using dot-notation, provided that they  have different return types/arguments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Starting `Scala 2.13` you can use the [`pipe`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/util/ChainingOps.html#pipe[B](f:A=%3EB):B) chaining operator:

```
import scala.util.chaining._

// def addNumber(i: Int, s: String) = s + i
// def doubleString(s: String) = (s + s, (s + s).length)
// def trimString(i: (String, Int)) = i._1.substring(0, i._2-1)
"Hello".pipe(addNumber(1, _)).pipe(doubleString).pipe(trimString)
// "Hello1Hello"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can experiment with Scalaz:

```
  import scalaz._
  import Scalaz._

  def addNumber(i: Int, s: String) = s + i
  def doubleString(s: String) = (s + s, (s + s).length)
  def trimString(i: (String, Int)) = i._1.substring(0, i._2-1)

  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit  =
    println(addNumber(2, "44") |> doubleString |> trimString)
```