# Chaining operations on values without naming intermediate values

Tags: scala, functional-programming, pipe-forward-operator

Sometimes I perform a sequence of computations gradually transforming some value, like:

```
def complexComputation(input: String): String = {
  val first = input.reverse
  val second = first + first
  val third = second * 3
  third
}
```

Naming variables is sometimes cumbersome and I would like to avoid it. One pattern I am using for this is chaining the values using `Option.map`:

```
def complexComputation(input: String): String = {
  Option(input)
    .map(_.reverse)
    .map(s => s + s)
    .map(_ * 3)
    .get
}
```

Using `Option` / `get` however does not feel quite natural to me. Is there some other way this is commonly done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chaining function in scala using dot notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54815867/chaining-function-in-scala-using-dot-notation)

Comment: I agree it is similar, I am not sure about being duplicate, though. That question asks about chaining functions and the code uses named functions (actually methods in Scala terminology?). Here I talk about chaining arbitrary blocks of code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, it will be possible with [Scala 2.13](https://github.com/scala/scala/milestone/67). It will introduce   [pipe](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/util/ChainingOps.html#pipe[B](f:A=%3EB):B):

```
import scala.util.chaining._

input //"str"
 .pipe(s => s.reverse) //"rts"
 .pipe(s => s + s) //"rtsrts"
 .pipe(s => s * 3) //"rtsrtsrtsrtsrtsrts"
```

Version [2.13.0-M1](https://www.scala-lang.org/download/2.13.0-M1.html) is already released. If you don't want to use the milestone version, maybe consider using [backport](https://index.scala-lang.org/bigwheel/util-backports/util-backports/1.1?target=_2.12)?

Comment: Interesting to know, this will be nice. I guess one should be able to implement `pipe` on his own easily. The only thing I am unsure of is getting the result without calling some `.get` eventually. Is there an implicit conversion used for that?

Comment: @Suma You'd only need a `get` if you wanted to extract it from the option. Question is, why are you using `Option` to begin with? To handle null?

Comment: Oh, I see my misconception now, it is pimped to everything and it is returning the plain value. I supposed it is returning something like `Option`, hence the need to call `get`.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov No. It's just a surrogate for the not-really-existent `Id` monad. If there were proper support for an `Id` monad, one wouldn't even need `pipe`, because it would be the same as `map` on the `Id` monad.

Comment: @Suma checkout [source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.0-M5/src/library/scala/util/ChainingOps.scala#L44).It is dead simple. It is just an extension method which is added to every class.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I see what you're saying, he's lifting it into an `Option` just to get the operations on String.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, it's doable to implement `pipe` on your own, e.g.:

```
implicit class Piper[A](a: A) {
  def pipe[B](f: A => B) = {
    f(a)
  }
}

val res = 2.pipe(i => i + 1).pipe(_ + 3)
println(res)  // 6

val resStr = "Hello".pipe(s => s + " you!")
println(resStr)  // Hello you!
```

Or take a look at https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.0-M5/src/library/scala/util/ChainingOps.scala#L44.