# Scala List equivalent of Lodash _.thru()

Tags: javascript, scala, lodash, seq

The Scala List API has a variety of functional methods similar to Lodash:

- https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.4/scala/collection/immutable/List.html
- https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#thru

I am looking for the Scala equivalent of the Lodash .thru() function for chaining, which is like .map() except it is called once and passes in the entire list as an argument, rather than the individual items in the List.

Comment: Is it the same as the not-yet-existent `|>`? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55020960/chaining-operations-on-values-without-naming-intermediate-values), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54815867/chaining-function-in-scala-using-dot-notation), or maybe skim through the results of [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bscala%5D+pipe-forward). In a nutshell: no, there is no pipe-forward in 2.12, there will be one in 2.13, until then it's very easy to define your own or use Scalaz's implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Scala 2.13** introduced [ChainingOps](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/util/ChainingOps.html) which provide `pipe` method, that makes probably what you expect.

```
import scala.util.chainingOps._ //need to be imported, to make pipe available

List(1,2,3)
   .pipe(l => 0 :: l) // List(0, 1, 2, 3)
```

If you can't use **Scala 2.13** yet, I would just fall back to pattern matching:

```
List(1,2,3) match {
    case l => 0 :: l
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55021136/2707792 ; And this `: List` is neither necessary nor valid, because type parameter is missing.